# Variable Scope in Tcl

Tags: tcl, scope

I have the following basic code:

```
proc test {} { 
    set my_var2 3
    foreach iter {1 2 3} {
        set my_var1 4
        set my_var2 5
        puts "Inside: $my_var1 $my_var2\n"  
    }
    puts "outside $my_var1, $my_var2\n"    ;#WHY IT DOES NOT GIVE ERROR HERE!
}
test  ;#calling the function
```

The output of the program is this:

```
Inside: 4 5

Inside: 4 5

Inside: 4 5

outside 4, 5
```

Now my confusion is since `my_var1` is define only in the local scope of foreach loop why its value is available even outside the loop? In other words what determines the scope of a variable in Tcl?
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: curly brackets are more like quotes in TCL, they don't intrinsically have anything to do with scope.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [the Tcl Manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/tutorial/Tcl13.html):

> Tcl evaluates variables within a scope delineated by procs, namespaces
>   [...], and at the topmost level, the global scope.

So the foreach loop does not create a new scope and all your variables are scoped by the proc.